# What is the easiest to hash color code Excel cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to find a way to color a column with IDs to see equal IDs easier. Ideally this would take the string value and color this or a neighboring cell such that equal string values get the same color (maybe a color from a fixed list of selected colors).

Is there a way with Excel commands or is it easy with VBA?

Comment: Conditional formatting might work to achieve this. Just depends on how many values you are expecting to be the same and if the values are static or dynamic. If they are dynamic, VBA is probably the better option

Comment: If you have a (large enough) list of colors you can use VBA to loop over the cells and use a scripting dictionary to store unique values and their associated colors.